# Date difference in days is different in different location environment

Tags: java, java-7

Below is giving me 279 days in local but in different server it is giving me 278 why this happening ?

```
String sDate = "10-11-2017";
String eDate = "16-08-2018";
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat(MsmConstants.DATE_FORMAT).parse(sDate);
Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat(MsmConstants.DATE_FORMAT).parse(eDate);
long difference = startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();
return Math.abs(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: what is the timezone of your server. Because date values(+/- 1) differs based on your timezone.

Comment: @Shriram if both `Date` objects are made using the same timezone, shouldn't the difference always be the same?

Comment: What's the `MsmConstants.DATE_FORMAT`? Also can you provide the exact `double` result you are getting, without the `Math.abs()`?

Comment: Both date are in past then why this difference is coming

Comment: MsmConstants.DATE_FORMAT ="dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: What timezone do you have on your local PC?

Comment: I got your point . Thanks

Comment: Indian Standard Time

Comment: OK. So Indian Standard Time doesn't have daylight savings right? Check what the timezone is on the server, I bet you will find it is some US or EU time which has daylight savings.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably coming from some kind of rounding combined with a difference in timezones.

Since both operands on the left and right of your `/` operator are integral types, you are actually losing precision with that operator.

If you change your expression to: `(double) difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`
you will notice that the result is actually: `-278.9583333333333`

The reason it is not exact days is because of daylight savings and similar date/time adjustments.

If on your PC you have different regional settings from the server, which do not have the same daylight savings, then you might have got a different number, which exceeded `279`.

As a sidenote, the Java 7 and earlier date/time API was very buggy. `SimpleDateFormat` wasn't even thread safe, and there were lots of issues with daylight savings and similar situations. You should really move to Java 8. What you are doing would simply become: `Duration.between(startDate, endDate)` and the calculation would be done correctly for you.

```
String sDate = "10-11-2017";
String eDate = "16-08-2018";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDate.parse(sDate, formatter).atTime(0, 0);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDate.parse(eDate, formatter).atTime(0, 0);

return Duration.between(startDate, endDate).toDays();
```

You will see that this actually gives you `279`.

Comment: Rounding is indeed imprecise due to how floating point numbers are represented internally. However, while imprecise, it is *deterministic*. The same input will yield the same output across all JVMs, or even across all IEEE 754 implementations.

Comment: Great . Thanks :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes the rounding is the same across JVMs. But if the timezone is different, then that little difference in the result could result in the precision truncated to 278 in 279.

Answer (score 1):

jbx has already in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038418/5772882) explained nicely what went wrong. 10 November is in winter on the Northern hemisphere, and 16 August is in summer. Between those two dates summer time (DST) begins, which causes one day to be just 23 hours, so the difference you calculate is 1 hour short of being 279 days at you had expected and had observed locally.

### java.time

Date and time math is too complicated and error-prone to do yourself the way you tried. You should always leave it to a well-proven library. Here’s the correct and modern solution.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MM-uuuu");
    String sDate = "10-11-2017";
    String eDate = "16-08-2018";
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(sDate, dateFormatter);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(eDate, dateFormatter);
    long difference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
    System.out.println(Math.abs(difference));
```

Output is the expected:

> 279

Since your date strings haven’t got time of day, there is no reason to use `LocalDateTime`. `LocalDate` is the correct class to use. It also makes sure that no number truncation can happen since there is always a whole number of days between two dates.

### Question: Will that work on Java 7?

Yes, java.time just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Nice explanation how to use the backport library for Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDataFormat` uses the JVM's default timezone to create `Date` objects. In case of daylight saving time, this might result in a +/- 1 day difference between two dates.

You have a couple of options:

1. Explicitly set the timezone of your `SimpleDateFormat` objects to GMT/UTC.
2. Explicitly set the timezone of your JVM to GMT/UTC.
3. In Java 8, use the new `java.time` API; in earlier versions of Java use an alternative like [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).